# How to deduce any view of a 3D object knowing all it's 2D views (top, down, front, back...)

Tags: image-processing, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

Well, the title is quite self explanatory. I'm asking a way to calculate any view of a 3D object knowing it's rotation and all the 6 views (proyected on a cube; top, bottom, front, back...). Is it even posible?

(answer to the first comment)
I'm asking about a way to create an arbitrary 2D projection of the 3D object from a number of 2D views. Without having to create the 3D object first and then having to project it into 2D.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to reconstruct an arbitrary 3D view from a number of 2D projections? Sorry, just clarifying your question. If so - the answer is maybe - massive subject, look here first http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_reconstruction_from_multiple_images

Comment: No, I was asking about the construcion of an arbitrary 2D projection of a 3D object from a number of 2D projections. Without having to create the 3D object itself, and then having to proyect it on a plane. Is it possible to do it directly?

Comment: Its not clear that all he has is a silhouette (outline) of each view.  @user11615 maybe an example showing what info you have to work with would be useful.  My WAG you can constuct a bounding envelop of possible shapes, but not get to the exact unique shape.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. Even if you have much more 3D views than in your case it is not generally possible.

The underlying problem is known in the literature as **shape from silhouette** or **visual hull**. This is the problem of finding 3D shape from multiple 2D projections, and knowing the 3D shape is a prerequisite for what you want to know (a new 2D projection).

If you google for the two concepts you will find plenty of interesting algorithms.

The quality of the approximation of 3D shape from 2D projections depends on the geometry of the original 3D shape, on the number of projections available and on the placement of the cameras that generate these projections, so success is highly dependent on your individual problem. Six views, however, are almost certainly insufficient unless you have a very specific type of 3D shape.

Comment: Exactly.  No matter how many views of a sphere you draw, you can never recover the fact that it's a sphere.  It could be the solid of intersection of a bunch of circular cylinders.